# How to create dynamic struct array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, struct

Im trying to learn dynamic arrays in C++. For integer, dynamic arrays are like that:

```
int main()
{    
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    int *dynamic = new int[x];
    //some codes
    delete [] dynamic;

    return 0;
}
```

How can i create dynamic struct array? I tried this code and i failed.

```
struct Phone{
    char name[30];
    char number[20];
}

int main(){
    int x;
    cin >> x;

    Phone *record;
    Phone *record = new Phone[x];// Code fails here
```

}

Im so confused in dynamic arrays. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: What does the actual error message say?

Comment: Program breaks when i tried to enter record[0].name and number

Comment: What makes you think having two `record` declarations is necessary (or allowed) just because the type changed?

Comment: I tried the code without Phone *record;

Comment: shldn't it be Phone *record = new Phone; then *record.name = something and *record.number = something? btw number should  be of type int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in syntax between allocating an `int` and allocating a `struct`.

Your syntax is correct. You're just defining the `record` pointer twice. Remove the first definition and you're all set (oh, and missing a semicolon after the `struct{}` declaration).

Note that modern C++ would probably prefer using an existing STL container (`vector<Phone>` or similar) instead of manually calling `new` and `delete[]`. I assume this is for learning, not for production code.

Comment: Can you suggest me a source about that (especially structs)?

Comment: I would just refer to Stroustrup's "The C++ Programming Language", but depending on your experience you might be looking for a more beginner-friendly book.

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest to rather use an std::vector. It's going to save you a lot of issues and memory bugs.  Just do:

```
struct structName 
{
     ...
}

std::vector<structName> structVector;
```

Then to get the values onto the vector do a

```
 structVector.push_back(structName{});
```